# Panasonic G2 rejects Lenmar battery: what should I do?

Tags: panasonic, battery

Lenmar is, to the best of my knowledge, a reputable manufacturer of aftermarket batteries.

I bought a DLPBLB13 battery as a 2nd battery for my Panasonic G2, charged it up, put it in my camera, checked for a few seconds to make sure it worked, and went off on a day trip, unfortunately leaving my original camera battery (Panasonic DMW-BLB13PP) home. When I went to use my camera, about 12 seconds after I turned it on, it complains "THIS BATTERY CANNOT BE USED", locks up for a little while, and shuts off. I had to give up shooting with the G2 and use my old point + shoot instead -- grr.

Now what should I do? Has anyone dealt with Lenmar before? I either want my money back or a camera battery that works.

Comment: Panasonic have in the past issued firmware updates, the purpose of which was __only__ to stop 3rd party batteries from working.

Comment: Sorry for being flippant but the obvious answer is: buy a Panasonic battery. I know it's annoying when manufacturers jack up the price on basic items, but it all goes to subsidise the lenses and camera bodies at the end of the day.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding getting money back - call the dealer, we can't help you.

For future - buy brand batteries :) When you knowingly buy a camera that is publicly said to operate only with brand batteries and you pay a lot of money for it - why try to cheat then?

I've personally never had good experience with 3rd party batteries and have cried but paid ~$150 for the Canon originals. On the other hand, they've never let me down either.

Comment: yeah, I guess you're right. What steams me is that I didn't know it operated *only* with OEM batteries. I wasn't trying to cheat them, I bought from a reputable battery maker a battery which I thought was a valid 2nd-source of the OEM battery. I never have had any interest in buying batteries from shady mfrs.

Comment: There's no good reason for an item to refuse to work with functionally-equivalent 3rd party accessories. I think @Jason is right to be steamed and not trying to cheat anyone.

Comment: Panasonic being one of the biggest battery manufacturers, I would be highly surprised if they were not the OEM. Lenmar probably makes a poor clone. For other brands of cameras which are not battery-manufacturers, like Canon, Nikon and Pentax, you can probably find the OEM and buy the equivalent battery from them.

Comment: "Lenmar probably makes a poor clone." ????? I've had a Panasonic FZ20 for nearly 6 years, and when I bought it in Dec 2004, I immediately bought a 2nd battery which was a Lenmar battery. The two batteries are both still holding up fine. So Lenmar has earned my trust and I would have gladly used their battery in my camera if Panasonic hadn't enabled the anti-3rd-party feature.